# OS X spotlight UI bug

Tags: macos, mac, spotlight

The spotlight search UI on my mac seems to have broken. It doesn't have a rounded corners. Nothing seems to solve it.
[image]

Comment: What makes you think this is a bug?

Comment: What computer are you using?

Comment: 13 inch MBP late 2014.

Comment: @tron_jones i said UI bug. maybe just UI glitch. can u solve it ?

Comment: I don't think its either, Every machine I have looks the same.  Is their a preference you have checked that you think it should be rounded corners?

Comment: On my Mac with Yosemite (10.10.4) the corners are square. On the El Capitain beta they do show as rounded. This is likely just changes Apple has made between versions of the OS.

Comment: It was round previously, until i installed an spotlight plugin. Later i uninstalled the plungin and the ul is broken. 
It might not seem clear in the pic but show very odd on my MBPR display.

Comment: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204014 and https://www.apple.com/osx/design (at the bottom) both show OS X Yosemite Spotlight with rounded corners.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The corners become squared when you have reduce transparency turned on in accessibility.

¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Thanks ! finally got it. my OCD was killing me. now i can sleep :)

Answer (score -1):

The corners are supposed to be squared, at least until El Capitan (10.11) arrives in the fall.