# Spotlight dark dictionary results with dark mode in Yosemite 10.10.4

Tags: macos, spotlight, dictionary

Spotlight gives dark dictionary results with some words when dark mode is on:

[image]

I've had this problem since day one of Yosemite.

iMac (27-inch, Late 2009)

Comment: Try System Preference > Accessibility > Display > Reduce Transparency On

Comment: That screenshot is with Reduce Transparency On. Take notice of the rounded corners, spotlight has squared corners with Reduce Transparency Off (see http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/198924/os-x-spotlight-ui-bug/199069#199069). Either way, it makes no difference.