# make dictionary result white text in spotlight in mojave dark theme

Tags: macos, mojave, spotlight, dictionary

[image]

I can't read the result. How do I make the text white?

I am on macOS Mojave 10.14.4

Comment: Verified the behavior on my Mac. Interestingly enough all other results show as white text. This may be a bug in Spotlight/dictionary. highlighting the text makes it a little more readable, but still... tsk, tsk, tsk, Apple

Comment: running 10.14.2. no issues. appears white

Comment: Also no issues on 10.14.3, confirmed on 10.14.4. Interestingly, [seems to correlate](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/199072/spotlight-dark-dictionary-results-with-dark-mode-in-yosemite-10-10-4) with .4 releases ;-)

Comment: Still the same in 10.14.5 b2 - will check b3 later today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug exists in 10.14.4 and earlier and It is fixed in 10.14.5